# Hiding pages in two userforms - runtime error 5

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, userform

I have two different userforms. The first UserForm has a multipage with 10 pages and 56 checkboxes. The second UserForm has one multipage with 56 pages. I have written a code that runs through all the checkboxes in UserForm1 and shows or hides the page in UserForm2, depending on the value of the checkbox.

Briefly explained: If checkbox1 in UserForm1 is true, then page1 is shown in UserForm2. If Checkbox1 in UserForm1 is false, then Page1 in UserForm2 is hidden. The loop should do this for each of the 56 checkboxes. Unfortunately, I keep getting runtime error 5. The debugger shows me the error in the line: `UserForm2.MultiPage1("Page" & i).Visible = False`.  I really appreciate your help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Hide
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 56
    If UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True Then
        UserForm2.MultiPage1("Page" & i).Visible = True
    ElseIf UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = False Then
        UserForm2.MultiPage1("Page" & i).Visible = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint, not answer : You could condense this to `UserForm2.MultiPage1("Page" & i).Visible =UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value`

Comment: So you show the forms modal or non-modal? Is Userform2 open at all?  What is the value of `i` when the runtime error happens? Can it be that either one of the checkboxes or pages doesn't follow the naming?

Comment: I have a command button which opens the Userform1 non-modal (`UserForm1.Show vbModeless`). However, Userform2 is not opened when Userform1 is edited. The variable `i` always has the value where the first checkbox is `false`. I have already checked the names of the pages and checkboxes, so the error can't be there.

Comment: Note: If all checkboxes are true, then the code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The error was that the index of pages starts counting at 0. In addition, I added the following code to the button that opens UserForm1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
UserForm2.Show vbModeless
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
UserForm2.Hide
End Sub
```

The loop now looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Hide
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 55
    If UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True Then
        UserForm2.MultiPage1.Pages(i - 1).Visible = True
    ElseIf UserForm1.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = False Then
        UserForm2.MultiPage1.Pages(i - 1).Visible = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use the index *number*, you are right, it starts at 0. But in your question you used the *name* that likely started with 1. And it doesn't explain why the code was working when you showed all pages.